# Will I be charged for 2 AWS Workspaces, if I delete the one I have and replace it with a new one within one month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to setup AWS Worskspace, the machine works fine, but for Connect Directory I always see the status failed. The message I get is. I tried joining Amazon EC2 instance to the Directory and it was successful. Also I installed AD Tools and was able to enable/disable user accounts.

```
Connectivity issues detected: DNS unavailable (TCP port 53) for IP: 172.192.14.53, DNS unavailable (TCP port 53) for IP: 172.192.29.235. Please ensure that the listed ports are available and retry the operation
```

What am I missing (I have not admin experience)? I cannot find a way to retry the operation and I don't know what operation it is talking about. However I have workspace(experimental) running. When I try to delete the Connect Directory I get the message

```
Are you sure you want to delete the following directory? This will delete all users, groups, and computers that are defined by the directory, and the directory cannot be recovered.
```

I am assuming it will also delete my workspace and the machine I am running. So will I be charged another $60 if I get a new workspace - replace this with a new one - after this one is deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Directory differs from Connect Directory. While Cloud Directory is AWS Managed and is like a Active/Domain Directory, Connect Directory is the connection to On Premise Directory. We don't need both of them. We can work with either.

If I delete a workspace any billed charges will not be returned. However if I launch a workspace after the 1st day of Month, then the cost would be prorated. So if I launch it on 5th Day for a $60 workspace in a month of 30 days I would be billed $(60/30*(30-11)) = $52 (10th day is included as full day).

Even if I delete all my workspace I can decide to keep Cloud Directory/Connect Diretory, I don't incur cost for it.

Thanks.